# PayPal IPN Validation Not Working Only for recurring_payment txn_type

Tags: node.js, paypal-ipn

My PayPal IPNs are validating fine, except for those with a txn_type of recurring_payment. When I pass the message to the validation endpoint, I'm converting the body into a query string using

```
var verificationString = '?cmd=_notify-validate';

Object.keys(body).map((key) => {
    verificationString = verificationString + '&' + key + '=' + body[key];
    return key;
});
```

My best guess is that this is messing with the order of the properties. PayPal's documentation states:

> Your listener HTTPS POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal; the message must contain the same fields (in the same order) as the original message and be encoded in the same way as the original message.

But I didn't think Object.keys(body).map would rearrange anything in Nodejs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Turns out that PayPal allows user fields to contain things like backslash, newline characters, etc. This specific IPN had an address field with a \r\n newline between the street and apartment number. Using my original code, this was somehow being encoded different.

Instead of assembling the query string like in my original question, I now assemble it like this, since it preserves all characters and encoding:

`var verificationString = '?cmd=_notify-validate&' + request.rawBody.toString();`

And that solved the problem!